# DispatchSemaphore cause app frozen, how to resolve it

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, grand-central-dispatch

when i run code, i click iphone home button, then reopen my app,my app is frozen.i feel uncertain,why?

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.aiswei.asw.monitior.search",qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 30)
        let minX = 2
        let maxX = 254
        self.index = minX
self.index = minX
        let count = maxX - minX + 1
        let lock = NSLock()
        for i in minX...maxX {
            queue.async {
                semaphore.wait()
                lock.lock()
                // request some server api  result
                 NetCenter.requestAPi { (result) in
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            
                lock.unlock()
              
            }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this to try to create over 250 threads, which you don't want to do. That said, my suspicion is that the actual problem is with coming in the foreground is elsewhere; possibly in NetCenter. You're probably deadlocking the main queue (especially if NetCenter is written in the same style).

Rather than kicking off a ton of DispatchWorkItems and then blocking them, you can achieve the same thing by using a single DispatchWorkItem on a serial queue, with your semaphore. The serial queue will get rid of the need for the lock. This serializes 30 operations at a time, which is what I think you want.

```
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.aiswei.asw.monitior.search")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 30)

    queue.async {
        let minX = 2
        let maxX = 254
        for _ in minX...maxX {
            semaphore.wait()
            NetCenter.requestAPi { (result) in
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming here that `requestAPi` is an async method and will schedule its completion handler on some queue other than `queue`. (If NetCenter uses the same queue as this function, than that would definitely deadlock.)

Comment: i have 254 tasks, i just need to excute  less 30tasks at the same time.so i use DispatchSemaphore to limit. NetCenter.requestApi contains other thread task.

Comment: Then the above code should be exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks,@ Rob Napier, but when queue is excute.i  click home button.then i reopen my app.my app is frozen . is it a bug of  semaphore?

Comment: As I said, that bug is probably coming from elsewhere (or as an interaction between this code and other code). I would suspect either your NetCenter code, or your application delegate code. You would definitely want to start with your didEnterForeground code in the app delegate. If the answer is not obvious, keep removing code until the problem goes away, which will tell you where it's occurring. The code you posted is bad concurrency code that could cause lock-ups due to exhausting the thread pool, but the actual problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: thanks@Rob Napier,i did unstand what you explain . when i check my code, i find my codes have some different with yours.i put `for _ in minX...maxX` out of ` queue.async {}`. i wonder why my code work bad.

Comment: Moving the loop out of `async` tries to generate over 250 threads, which is far too many. Threads are relatively expensive and finite. My approach generates at most one thread (and possibly not even that).

Comment: Thanks I tried it and printed the log, it is indeed the case